# Showcase для программного продукта

Tags: презентации

Очередной "фишкой" от начальника стало придумывание showcase (витрины) для нашего программного продукта.

Какими они бывают, что можно предложить? У меня пока только три идеи:

1. Обычная презентация в PowerPoint с указанием используемых форматов и потоками данных.
2. Видео в том же ключе, что и презентация
3. Небольшая интерактивная флеш-анимация

Может, кто-то сталкивался, подскажете?

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Куда? Для чего? Если на сайт, то предлагаю заюзать что-нибудь типа slideshare.net или sliderocket.com

Comment: Нет, не для сайта. Для отчета вышестоящему начальству. Showcase, показывающий, что все работает...

Comment: Какой уровень начальства и главное - продукт для внутреннего использования, одному (двум) заказчикам или на продажу ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот теперь понятнее. Ну у нас бывают такие варианты:

1. Вордовский файл со криншотами и описанием, аля справка для пользователя.
2. Презенташка также со скринами, но поменьше описания, только основное. Может потребоваться докладчик для объяснения.
3. Иногда делаю скринкаст, можно с комментами или субтитрами. Народу очень нравится этот формат. Не нужен докладчик.
4. Просто демонстрация на рабочем примере, чтобы можно было кнопочки поклацать.

Comment: А вот это как раз то, что мне нужно, мерси.

Answer (score 2):

Зависит, разумеется, от **целевой аудитории и обстоятельств**, при которых этот `showcase` будет демонстрироваться, но форматы таких `showcase` известны и вряд ли стоит пытаться придумать что-то "свое и новенькое".

**Классика** - краткая емкая презентация с одной-двумя видеовставками. На создание и расположение видеовставок стоит обратить особое внимание, поскольку в таких презентациях видео обычно производит главную часть *"вау-эффекта".* *Также, на мой взгляд, стоит нанять дизайнера, а не делать эти вещи самому, т.к самодельные презентации обычно легко отличить от профессионально сделанных.*

---

Если это все переезжает на просторы интернета, то формат тоже известен - красиво рассказать о возможностях с помощью видео или **неинтерактивно** и прямо на страницах браузера.

**Неинтерактивно** потому, что пользователь хочет просто просмотреть краткую выдержку информации о возможностях, а не что-то там тыкать, чтобы ему эти возможности показали. **Интерактивность** может быть только лишь в том случае, если вы можете дать пользователю *"пощупать"* продукт прямо на страницах браузерах *(то есть, в некотором демо-режиме*).

---

Хорошие примеры всего этого *(разумеется, субъективно)*:

- [**Возможности Google Chrome**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chHxNAJ8B1U)
- [**Что умеет `IntelliJ IDEA`**](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/)
- *(небольшой оффтоп :)* [**Су-35 Глубокая модернизация**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dKb3N6x7PVA) и [**Инфографика про Су-35С**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3iQXPXiglC0)